# Secure and valid way for converting a "float integer" into a natural integer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a CGFloat that contains only "integers", in the meaning that it actually wants to represent integers only but due to float inprecision it may happen that it internally has a 23.00000000000000000000000142 or something like that. I try to feed an NSDecimalNumber with clean input, so I need to make sure this is truly a naked integer with no dirt. Well, I think this is a good way, but maybe I am wrong:

NSInteger *intVal = floatVal;

That would just get rid of those fragmental parts at the end of the tale, right? Or is there a more secure way to convert it into a true integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to take the integer part of a float then I believe you can just do the following:

```
CGFloat myfloat = 23.0000000000142f;
int myInt = (int) myfloat;
```

Comment: that makes sense. Would that also work with NSInteger? Would that make a difference than assigning the float to a NSInteger without prior casting it like this? I'm not sure what's going on under the hood but could imagine it does something like that?

Comment: Yes it should work with NSInteger.  If memory serves me correct NSInteger is defined as either an int or a long, either way this should still work.